# What is the difference between assigning a value to an index of an array and assigning a value to the alias of the index of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public string[] arrTestResults = new string[8];
public string TestName;
[TestInitialize]
 public void SetupTest()
    {
        // Assigning aliases to array indexes
        TestName = arrTestResults[0] = "";
    }


  public void General()
    {
        arrTestResults[0] = "Test 1: General"; // works

        TestName = "Test 1: General"; // does not work. Quick Watch says TestName = Null. WHY?
```

Comment: when you say "does not work", what do you mean? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I did a quick watch and saw that TestName = Null

Comment: What type of object is TestName? show us it's declaration

Comment: TestName gets "", not what at position 0 of arrTestResults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestName` is NOT an alias to `arrTestResults[0]`.

I'm assuming that `arrTestResults` is `string[]` and that `TestName` is too.

`arrTestResults[0]` is a storage location whose value refers to an instance of `string`.

`TestName` is a storage location whose value refers to an instance of `string`.

```
TestName = arrTestResults[0] = "";
```

does not make `TestName` an alias for `arrTestResults[0]`. Instead, it assigns to the storage location `TestName` and to the storage location `arrTestResults[0]` a reference to an instance of `string` that is equal to `""`. That is, there is a reference to `""`. That reference is assigned to `arrTestResults[0]` and to `TestName`. It is quite similar to

```
int y = 0;
int x = y = 17;
```

Here, `x` is NOT an alias for `y`. We have just copied the value `17` to `y` and to `x`. In our case, the value is the reference. A reference to `""` is copied to `arrTestResults[0]` and to `TestName`.

Then

```
arrTestResults[0] = "Test 1: General";
```

assigns a new reference to the storage location `arrTestResults[0]`.

It's quite like

```
y = 42;
```

And then

```
 TestName = "Test 1: General";
```

assigns a new reference to the storage location `TestName`. It does not alter the value of `arrTestResults[0]` because these two storage locations are different. Again, this is quite like

```
x = 69;
```

This does not alter the value of `y`.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question title shows the potential misunderstanding here:

> the alias of the index of the array

When you assign a string like so:

```
TestName = arrTestResults[0];
```

You're NOT assigning an alias to what's contained in `arrTestResults[0]`, rather, you're copying the reference to the string `arrTestResults[0]` is pointing to into `TestName`.  This is a *copy of the reference* to a string, but not an alias.

Later, when you assign a value to `TestName`:

```
TestName = "Test 1: General";
```

This copies a *new reference*, overwriting the old one.  It does nothing to the reference in the array, as that's a separate copy.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an alias; it's an independent variable.

It is not possible to make a variable that is an alias to another variable or to an array element (unless you use unsafe code).